# Не устанавливается библиотека через composer

Tags: php, api, github, composer, library

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку https://github.com/amocrm/amocrm-api-php

В консоли хостинга в папке где лежит composer ввожу `composer require amocrm/amocrm-api-library`

Выдает ошибку

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Package amocrm/amocrm-api-library has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из этого я понимаю что ругается на версию PHP.
Сама среда у меня версия 7.3

Composer пытался обновить командой composer update - не помогло

Что еще проверять?
Добавляю что еще сделал:
Обновил Composerкомандой `composer self-update`
теперь другая ошибка выдается

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
```

Package amocrm/amocrm-api-library has a PHP requirement
incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:
- amocrm/amocrm-api-library 0.6.1 requires php >=7.1 which does not match your installed version 5.6.40.

из этого опять же понимаю что ругается на версию среды якобы она 5.6.40 но захожу на хостинг и проверяю версия 7.3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может где то в другом месте нужно проверять версию PHP?...

Comment: композер обновляют командой `self-update` а не `update`. последней вы зависимости обновляете

Comment: Я обновил командой  'self-update' - не помогло((

Comment: если вы композер запускаете из командной строки, то почему для проверки версии пхп лезете к веб серверу, а не через `php -v` ?

Comment: там в хостинге мб и указан путь к пхп, а-ля `/usr/bin/php73` вот с ним целиком и запускайте

Comment: Спасибо. Да проверил командой `php -v` пишет версия PHP 5.6.40. Странно(((. а как ее изменить? тут наверно от хостера зависbт как устанавливается версия PHP?

Comment: что нить такое по итогу получится `/usr/bin/php7.3 /usr/local/bin/composer require ...`. либо алиасы пропишите

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Действительно была проблема в версии PHP
Я использую хостинг beget.com и для установки библиотеки использовал консольный интерпретатор командной строки.

в моем случае, устанавливать библиотеку нужно такой командой `composer-php7.3 require amocrm/amocrm-api-library`
т.е. после composer нужно указать версию PHP

Comment: у меня такая ошибка в версию php, попробовал ваш способ не получилось композер находится по адресу /var/www/u1456792/data/www/mympresario.truestudio.ru/core

запускаю так и выдает ошибку
-bash-4.2$ composer-php7.4 require diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs
-bash: composer-php7.4: команда не найдена